# I need to get data with .data() method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <ul class="list">
  <li class="element" data-element="element A">element A</li>
  <li class="element" data-element="element B">element B</li>
  <li class="element" data-element="element C">element C</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This is my code:

```
const data = $('.wrapper .list . element').data('element');
console.log(data)
```

The result in the console is only the first element - element A. But I need each of them.
Because I want to use them next way, e.g.:

```
if (data === 'element A') return $('li').css('color', 'red');
if (data === 'element B') return $('li').css('color', 'blue');
if (data === 'element C') return $('li').css('color', 'green');
```

Comment: Why not get the one you want in the first place?  `$("[data-element='element A']").css("color", "red");`?  No need for the `if`, no need to `loop`, no need for `.data()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Loop your elements using the [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) jQuery method
- Fix your selectors, `". element"` is invalid. Should be `".element"` or rather: `"[data-element]"`

```js
$(".list [data-element]").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).data("element"));
});
```

but here's my suggestion how to tackle the task using an Object as colors reference:

```js
const dataColors = {
  "element A": "red",
  "element B": "blue",
  "element C": "green",
};

$("[data-element]").each((i, el) => {
  $(el).css({"color": dataColors[$(el).data("element")]});
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <ul class="list">
  <li class="element" data-element="element A">element A</li>
  <li class="element" data-element="element B">element B</li>
  <li class="element" data-element="element C">element C</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in vanilla JavaScript it's also pretty simple:

```js
const dataColors = {
  "element A": "red",
  "element B": "blue",
  "element C": "green",
};

const ELS_data = document.querySelectorAll("[data-element]");
ELS_data.forEach(el => el.style.color = dataColors[el.dataset.element]);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <ul class="list">
  <li class="element" data-element="element A">element A</li>
  <li class="element" data-element="element B">element B</li>
  <li class="element" data-element="element C">element C</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Anyways, it seems quite odd to use JS for that task - with **hardcoded** values of colors.

It would make sense if you had something **dynamic**, values that JavaScript has to consume from a HTML attribute like `data-color="orange"`

```js
const ELS_data = document.querySelectorAll("[data-color]");
ELS_data.forEach(el => el.style.color = el.dataset.color);
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <ul class="list">
  <li class="element" data-color="red">element A</li>
  <li class="element" data-color="hsl(200, 80%, 70%)">element B</li>
  <li class="element" data-color="#fb0">element C</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Otherwise, **CSS would suffice**:

```css
[data-element="element A"] { color: red; }
[data-element="element B"] { color: blue; }
[data-element="element C"] { color: green; }
/* etc... */
```

because there's nothing dynamic.